# NetFilterHook: Interface Name blank

Tags: linux-kernel, hook, kernel-module, netfilter

I am fixing a problem that the kernel module can not detect the interface name by in->name, that is:
printk(KERN_INFO "%s\n", in->name);

The result is in->name is blank, and also the in->ifindex returns a negative value (-2123688349)

I do configured two interface as bridge mode using brctl and it can recognize the interface name using ifconfig (eth1 and eth2) and works fine.

Can someone help on this issue or any temp solutions?

Comment: Too few details. Please provide [minimal compilable example](http://www.sscce.org/) which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Where is your hook? Please put here your module code.